# Iterating through an array to find a hash value

Tags: ruby, arrays, regex, hash

I have two arrays. One that stores a strings `name` and one that stores hashes `people`. I'd like to filter the `people` array and find the one hash that either has a close/full match with one of the strings in my name array. So for instance *John* from `names` and *John Doe* would be consider a match because the both have *John* in them.

```
names = ["John", "Jane"]

people = [{name: "John Doe"}, {name: "Bill Bradley"}]
```

I tried matching the two using the `select` method but it returned an empty array?

```
people.select{|person| person["name"] == names.any?}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be one way:

```
names = ["John", "Jane"]    
people = [{name: "Johnny Jones"}, {name: "John Doe"}, {name: "Bill Bradley"}]

people.select { |h| hname = h[:name]; names.any? { |n| hname[/\b#{n}\b/i] } }
  #=> [{:name=>"John Doe"}]
```

The steps:

```
enum = people.select
  #=> #<Enumerator: [{:name=>"Johnny Jones"}, {:name=>"John Doe"},
  #                  {:name=>"Bill Bradley"}]:select>
```

The first element of the enumerator is passed into the block and assigned to the block variable `h`:

```
h = enum.next
  #=> {:name=>"Johnny Jones"}
```

Next I create a temporary variable so we don't have to retieve `h[:name]` for each element of `enum` passed into the block:

```
hname = h[:name]
  #=> "Johnny Jones"
```

Then see if any element of `names` matches `"Johnny Jones"`:

```
names.any? { |n| hname[/\b#{n}\b/i] }
  #=> ["John", "Jane"].any? { |n| "Johnny Jones"[/\b#{n}\b/i] }
  #=> false
```

In the last expression, `"John"` is passed into the block and assigned to the block variable `n`. We then have:

```
"Johnny Jones"[/\bJohn\b/i]
  #=> nil
```

The first *word break* (`\b`) requires that `"John"` be immediately preceded by a non-word character (or be the first character of the string); the second word break requires that `"John"` be immediately followed by a non-word character (or be the last character in the string). Therefore, `"John"` does not match `"Johnny Jones"`.

The next (and last) element of `names` (`"Jane"` is then passed into the block and assigned to `n`. `"Johnny Jones"` doesn't match `"Jane"` either, so `any?` returns `false` and poor Johnny doesn't get selected.

In a similar manner, John Doe is selected and Bill Bradley is sent home.

Comment: Can you explain what the regex code is doing in the `any?` block?

Comment: Also you're missing a quote to close the string for `Johnny Jones`

Comment: I provided an explanation (and also noticed the missing quote, but thanks).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
matches = people.select do |person|
  !(names & person[:name].split(' ')).empty?
end

p matches #=> [{:name=>"John Doe"}]
```

Basically, you're first separating the hash value into individual words with `property[:name].split(' ')`. The result of this will be array like `['John', 'Doe']`. You then check if this newly created array has any common elements with the names array using the & operator. Thus, you get `names & property[:name].split(' ')`. If no matches are produced, you'll have an empty array which is NOT what you want, thus the `!` (not) operator. You could also do this if it's more intuitive:

```
matches = people.reject do |person|
  (names & person[:name].split(' ')).empty?
end
```

Also, if you'd like to get the hash itself rather than the hash wrapped in an array (or hashes, if there are multiple results), replace `select` with `detect`.